# JAXB's @XmlElement(name=" ") not working in Mule

Tags: java, jaxb, mule

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "AccountResponse")
public class AccountResponse {
    @XmlElement(name = "AccountNumber")
    protected long accountNumber;
     public long getAccountNumber() {
        return accountNumber;
    }
    public void setAccountNumber(long value) {
        this.accountNumber = value;
    }
}
```

In above mentioned code snippet, I am trying to decorate *accountNumber* with *AccountNumber* using @XmlElement annotation.Code is getting executed without throwing any exceptions. But not getting expected output.
How to solve this problem?

Expected Output :

```
<AccountResponse>
    <AcconutNumber>1234</AccountNumber>
</AccountResponse>
```

Actual Output(that I am getting) :

```
<AccountResponse>
    <acconutNumber>1234</accountNumber>
</AccountResponse>
```

NOTE : I am using a jar for JAXB from Mule Runtime Library 3.4 .

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: "But it is not working for me" is not enough information. What happens? Does it execute but not give you the output you want? Does it throw an exception? Please give details.

Comment: Sorry for insufficient information. It is getting executed without throwing any exceptions. But not getting expected output.

Comment: Please guess what my next question is *bound* to be, and edit your question to answer it. Read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is almost correct in my opinion, but you should try to use your annotation on getter instead of Field:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "AccountResponse")
public class AccountResponse {
    protected long accountNumber;

    @XmlElement(name = "AccountNumber")
    public long getAccountNumber() {
        return accountNumber;
    }
    public void setAccountNumber(long value) {
        this.accountNumber = value;
    }
}
```

Depending on your configuration, xml tag name may be created from your getter instead of your field name. In this case I guess it happened.

Comment: By default annotations should go on the get (or set method).  In this question `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)` is set on the class, therefore the annotation should go on the field:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/using-jaxbs-xmlaccessortype-to.html

Answer (score 0):

Running the following code on the `AccountResponse` class from your question:

```
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(AccountResponse.class);

        AccountResponse ar = new AccountResponse();
        ar.setAccountNumber(1234);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(ar, System.out);
    }

}
```

Will get you the XML response that you are expecting:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<AccountResponse>
    <AccountNumber>1234</AccountNumber>
</AccountResponse>
```

**Determining the Problem**

1. If you get the same output I do when running this demo code against your `AccountResponse` class then the issue is with Mule.
2. If you get different output then the `AccountResponse` class may not have been recompiled since you added the `@XmlElement(name = "AccountNumber")` annotation.